# I am trying to write a program to add two integer lists. Here is my implementation:

Tags: python-3.x, data-structures, linked-list

```
class Solution:

def addTwoListInt(self,l1,l2):
    if l1==None:
        return l2

    if l2==None:
        return l1

    res = None


    len1 = 0
    #head1=l1

    while l1!=None:
        len1+=1
        head1=head1.next

    len2 = 0
    #head2=l2

    while l2!=None:
        len2+=1
        head2=head2.next

    if len1<len2:
        longer = l2
        shorter = l1
    else:
        longer = l1
        shorter = l2

    carry = 0


    while shorter!=None:
        val = shorter.data + longer.data + carry
        carry = val//10
        val -= carry*10

        if res==None:
            res = Node(val)
            result = res
        else:
            res.next = Node(val)
            res = res.next

        shorter = shorter.next
        longer = longer.next

    while longer!=None:
        val = longer.data + carry
        carry = val//10
        val -= carry*10

        res.next = Node(val)
        res = res.next

        longer = longer.next

    if carry!=0:
        res.next = Node(carry)
        res=res.next

    return result
```

If I don't use head1 and head2 for l1 and l2 which are the headers of the lists then the function returns UnbondLocalError saying result has been referenced before assignment and it works if I do assign l1 and l2 as head1 and head2 and proceed the code with them. I want to know what is happening if I don't assign them locally in the function and why is it not working.

Comment: You seem to be overcomplicating things :)  What must be returned when the lengths of the lists differ?

Comment: My code runs perfectly when I use a local variable like head1/head2 here but it outputs an error if I try to use the parameter values directly. In some cases it works and in others it doesn't. I want an explanation about this. For the time being, ignore the complexity of the code.

Comment: I would expect something like this as an answer: 
a = [1, 2, 3];
b = [4, 5, 6];
map(lambda x,y: x+y, a, b);
Out[19]: [5, 7, 9].
But some modification is needed when the lists have different length. What is the expected result in this case?

Comment: I totally get your way of doing it. But here I am trying to implement this using linked list, from the scratch. My question is what is the problem if I don't assign a local variable for a passed-argument and use the argument for traversing the list?

Answer (score 0):

Without `head1` and `head2`, you'd have:

```
len1 = 0
while l1!=None:
    len1+=1
    l1=l1.next
// when the loop exits, l1==None

len2 = 0
while l2!=None:
    len2+=1
    l2=l2.next
// when the loop exits, l2 == None
```

At this point, both `l1` and `l2` are `None`. So you end up assigning `None` to both `shorter` and `longer`. As a result, neither of your loops is entered, and `res` is never assigned a value.